# How does EF tell apart TPC and TPT inheritance models?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

For Table Per Concrete Type model the whole entity is stored as a row in one table.
For Table Per Type additional tables contan only specific to descendant type data.

If the forst case EF issues one insert, and in the second one it must issue two inserts: for base and for inherited types' tables.

I cannot understand how EF knows what to do. The only difference I see now is just mappings in MSL: either they overlap or not.

Comment: Well, isn't that the answer? The mapping? See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) and the sequel.

Comment: @GertArnold May be it is, but the real problem is that we have unique constrainst along with PK. EF does not support Uniques, yet we have partially overlapped entities PK+UQ fields and neither TPT nor TPC fits our case. So the real question is whether it's possible to make EF write property (not PK) to several tables. Thanks for the link.